# Getting different result statistics in PyCharm and Terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I've got a list of proxies and I'm trying to connect to a website using these proxies.

When I run this script from Pycharm, the majority of my proxies seem to work just fine:

[image]

However, when I run the exact same script from terminal, I get the following statistics:

[image]

The results are consistent, meaning that if I ran the script on Pycharm for 4-5 times, I would get the same statistics where successful proxies would range from 1300-1500. Similarly from terminal, I would always get half of the successful proxies.

Now I have checked Pycharm's interpreter and the path was pointed to:
/home/danny/anaconda3/bin/python
The terminal's script interpreter was also the same: /home/danny/anaconda3/bin/python

Am I missing something? Maybe Pycharm does some kind of additional SSL logic? Any help would be really useful as I'm stuck at this point.

Python Version: 3.7.7

OS: Lubuntu LTS 18.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that in Linux the default ulimit from the terminal was 1024, so if that limit was surpassed, it was failing all other requests.

Solution is to increase this limit with the following cmd:

ulimit -n 4096 [where the limit will be now at 4096]